# Sql Server 2005 - Changing Collation

Tags: sql-server-2005, collation

suddenly we have to save kanji (Japanese) in a couple of columns of two or three tables.
I have tried to save to the db using the current collation which is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
However, I just get '?' for each character. I am going to need to change the collation to Japanese_CI_AS I presume.
My question is can I change the collation of the whole database? If not if I change the collation of a column will that override the database settings thus allowing me to store the kanji in that column correctly?

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to store Kanji in a handful of columns then you should set those columns to use the Japanese collation.  Setting the database collation to Kanji would be overkill - and would not change the collation of the columns IIRC - the collation specified at database level is the *default collation* which will affect creates from the point it is set onwards rather than affecting existing tables etc.

Answer (score 1):

I second Will A. And I don't think it is possible to change collation of entire database or installed SQL Server instance.

You can use alter statements to change the collation.

This article may help

[Setting and Changing the Column Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx)